# How to give permission to remote desktop user to Delete Private Queues

Tags: security, queue, msmq, private, remote-desktop

I have been trying various methods to give remote desktop users permission to delete private queue.
What i already tried is
From Admin account I went to *Computer Management > Service and Applications > Private Queues >*
Then i opened properties of the queues and went to security section to gave permissions to **remote desktop users** to **delete queues**.
This was success for one time but next time when queues were created again they had default securities and remote desktop users were unable to delete them.

Is there anyway to provide **remote desktop users** permission to delete queues everytime they are created??